# Power BI: How to Group by 7 Days Bin for Bar Chart to start from Monday instead of Sunday?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to create a barchart showing counts of events with Month View drilling down to Week and to days. I have created new groups, such as column "Month" by grouping 1 month in a bin and column "Week" by group 7 days in a bin. I noticed that when I drill down to week, it always starts on a Sunday. My client wanted to be on Monday. I've tried adding a new column "Week2" with "WeeK" dates + 1. The time axis does shows the date shifted by 1 but the data under that week still starts on Sunday. Attached is a screenshot of my barchart with group by week on Date.

Is it possible to change the Weekly Bar chart to start on Monday instead of Sunday for the drill down?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possible solution to your problem:

1. You could quickly create a small table to link to the day of the week you currently have on your table. Then on this table which would have the seven vaules for each day of the week you add a column with your prefered ordering (such as monday first) and then use the "Sort by column" option on the column tools in the top ribbon.
2. You could use a time dimension table, such as the one found [here](https://radacad.com/all-in-one-script-to-create-date-dimension-in-power-bi-using-power-query), you can specify in the script when the week starts, and you can remove all the columns you won't use.

I can't test your exact scenario at the moment, I hope one of these solution may work for you